# In Flutter Getx, what is the difference between `Get.parameters` and `Get.arguments`?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-getx

In `Getx` when navigating to a new page, you can pass data to the second page as 'arguments':

```
Get.toNamed('/second', arguments: {});
```

or as `parameters`

```
Get.toNamed('/second', parameters: {});
```

and in both cases, you can access this data using `Get.arguments` and `Get.parameters` accordingly.

So why are there two concepts if they achieve the same purpose?

Three differences I noticed:

1- parameters have to be of String type, and arguments can be of any type.

2- parameters get appended to the named route like so `/second?parameter1=value1`, arguments don't.

3- some classes in Getx can only accept arguments, not parameters for example:

`RouteSettings` can only take arguments although it requires a named route so it can theoretically accept parameters and append them after the route name.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

`Get.parameters`

Will grab the value of [query strings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) that are set by the `parameters : {}` part of the `Get.toNamed` method. Thus, the parameters defined will be displayed on the URL bar of a browser. This is commonly used on web development where you need to display some stuffs (like `id`s) and let the user change the value manually to get different data / view depending on what parameters available for filtering. That is why it appears in such format `endpoint/?parameter1=value1`

`Get.arguments`

In the other hand, will not display its values on the URL bar of a browser. This is commonly used in mobile / desktop development where query strings are not really necessary or when you don't want the user to be able to modify it directly in the runtime.